# Javascript Drag and drop return cordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I've been looking for a good tutorial on javascript drag and drop.
Not to move an element as a div or a canvas around or to resize it, but
just to return the movement of the drag.

Examples:

- Like the slingshot in angry birds or to move an image around in a
  canvas by dragging it.
- Moving the "map" by mouse drag.
- In a Div where i drag from point A to B in the same element without
  moving it around and just returning the movement without halting all
  the code already running

Examples I've found so far are moving elements by different frameworks by making the whole element draggable and that's not what I'm after so please point me in the right direction and you will be my hero of the day

Comment: You mean something like [PaperJs](http://paperjs.org/examples/chain/)?

Comment: It seems that paper.js has "onMouseDrag" wich works like i want but do i realy need to use that whole framework just for that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

It has loads of samples in the left and right panes and also details on how to use them,
Hope this helps you.

Or you can always just use the mousedown, mouseup and mousemove events to calculate them manually. Get to me with what you are comfortable with.

Comment: That is thru making the whole object draggable wich was not what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually do it, it’s pretty straight forward:

1 On mousedown, save the coords of the mouse in an object and bind a mousemove function that calculates the distance.

2 On mouseup, unbind the mousemove handler.

Here is some code examples:

```
var coords; // the starting point

var move = function(e) {
      var diffX = e.pageX - coords.x; // the moved x distance
      var diffY = e.pageY - coords.y; // the moved y distance
      console.log('move: '+diffX+'(x) '+diffY+'(y)');
    };

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  coords = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}; // saves the mouse position on mousedown
  $(this).mousemove(move);
}).mouseup(function() {
  $(this).unbind('mousemove', move);
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/okatoj/1 (watch the console)

Comment: That is somewhat what i'm looking for but it seems that solution wont return the drag until the mouse button is released.

Comment: @user1932567 return the what? It is the `move` function that gets called while dragging, and this example simply logs the movement x/y.

Comment: Yes but not until the mouse button is released :)
It is doh the closest thing i'm after out of all the replys.

Comment: @user1932567 I don’t know what you mean, the `move` function is called on `mousemove`. Did you try the demo and look into the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the coordinates of the mouse pointer you could use the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the `mousemove` event.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) { 
    console.log(e.clientX,e.clientY); 
},false);
```

That example attaches the listener to the `window` object , but you could do the same with other elements.. eg. `document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener`